# Proper way to export a marshaled struct

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am writing a managed DLL that uses a 3rd party native DLL whose header contains:

```cpp
typedef struct {
   Bool isMounted;
   char *symbolicLink;
} VolumeInfo;

ErrorCode GetVolumeInfo(VolumeHandle handle, VolumeInfo **info);
void FreeVolumeInfo(VolumeInfo *info);
```

I marshaled this as:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential]
internal struct NativeVolumeInfo
{
    public bool IsMounted;
    public IntPtr SymbolicLink;
}

static extern ErrorCode GetVolumeInfo(IntPtr volumeHandle, out IntPtr volumeInfoPointer);
static extern void FreeVlumeInfo(IntPtr volumeInfoPointer);
```

The rationale is:
- `VolumeInfo.SymbolicLink` has to be an `IntPtr` instead of `string` because its size is dynamic and I don't know what the charset is. Besides, the native code *is supposed to not set it* if `isMounted` is `false`, but this is not always the case and I sometimes ended up with gibberish from the unmanaged memory.
- I need to get the pointer to `volumeInfoHandle` from native and then pass it back for freeing. So I cannot simply pass the managed struct as `out` on `GetVolumeInfo` and rely on the marshaller to fill it in for me.

My goal is to expose this volume information to the end users of my DLL. So I have this API class that uses the native methods behind the scenes and returns a more user-friendly struct:

```cs
public struct VolumeInfo
{
  public bool IsMounted {get;set;}
  public string SymbolicLink {get;set;}
}

public class PublicApi
{
  public VolumeInfo GetVolumeInfo(Volume volume)
  {
    IntPtr volumeInfoPointer;
    var errorCode = NativeMethods.GetVolumeInfo(volume.Handle, out volumeInfoPointer);
    if (errorCode == 0)
    {
      var nativeVolumeInfo = (NativeVolumeInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(volumeInfoPointer, typeof(NativeVolumeInfo));
      try
      {
        var volumeInfo = new VolumeInfo { IsMounted = nativeVolumeInfo.IsMounted };
        if (volumeInfo.IsMounted)
        {
          volumeInfo.SymbolicLink = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(nativeVolumeInfo.SymbolicLink);
        }
        return volumeInfo;
      }
      finally
      {
        NativeMethods.FreeVolumeInfo(volumeInfoPointer);
      }           
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Didn't work");
  }
}
```

At this point I am worried that for every native struct that I need to marshal manually I have to write 2 managed structs: one for marshaling and another one to export to end-users.

Is there any way to make this easier?

Comment: Actually, you should probably expose the managed struct as a class instead, with a `Dispose` method and a finalizer. In .NET, every class should be able to clean-up after itself. Apart from that, consult the documentation of the API - `char *` isn't nearly enough information to implement this correctly. Unmanaged code is very much unsafe, so you have to be much more careful.

Comment: You are worrying about the wrong problem.  There's a memory management problem hidden in this code.  Who owns the string?  How is it supposed to be released?  Does a unit test crash on OOM when you call this function a billion times?  Hiding such nasty details is a foremost requirement on interop code.  If that requires a separate interop struct then so be it.

Comment: @HansPassant: My understanding is the string is allocated in the unmanaged memory. I only have to call `FreeVolumeInfo` when I'm done and this should take care of releasing it. I don't have to use `Marshal.FreeXXX` because I don't own it, right?